# Reach all possible rotations parametric to time.

Tags: rotations, matrix-calculus

I was recently playing with a CAD 3D modelling program.
Once you rotate a part using the mouse and let go, it keeps rotating the part using the rotation matrix provided by the mouse input.

The rotation is therefore given by:

$
\begin{align}
R_t &= R_x \cdot R_y \cdot R_z \cdot t \\
&=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi) \\
0 & -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)
\end{matrix}
\right]
\cdot
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos(\theta) & 0 & -\sin(\theta) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sin(\theta) & 0 & \cos(\theta)
\end{matrix}
\right]
\cdot
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos(\psi) & \sin(\psi) & 0 \\
-\sin(\psi) & \cos(\psi) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right] 
\cdot t \\
&=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos(\psi) \cos(\theta) & \sin(\psi) \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\psi) \\
-\sin(\psi) \cos(\phi) + \cos(\psi)\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) & \cos(\psi) \cos(\phi) + \sin(\psi)\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) & \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) \\
\sin(\psi) \sin(\phi) + \cos(\psi)\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) & -\cos(\psi) \sin(\phi) + \sin(\psi)\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) & \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi)
\end{matrix}
\right]
\cdot t
\end{align}
$
Where $t$ is the current time (ever increasing) and $\phi, \theta, \psi$ are the rotational inputs given by the mouse.

My question is rather simple;

- Does there exist a single combination of $\phi, \theta, \psi$ such that all possible rotations can be achieved by increasing the time $t$?

Note: I'm not from a mathematical background, so my apologies for any incorrections in my question statement.

Answer (score 1):

$R_t$ is not a rotation except if $t=1$. A rotation depends exactly on $3$ parameters, for example $\phi,\theta,\psi$.

EDIT. I think that, when you play, you select (with the mouse) an angle amongst the $3$ above, for instance $\phi$; then $\phi$ is changed with $\phi\pm t$ where $t$ is the time. If you want to reach any rotation, then you must successively make a change of all $3$ angles.

Comment: I do believe that I'm setting multiple rotation parameters at once.

Once a model is loaded, it's centered around origin $(0,0,0)$.

Clicking within the viewport, while seeing model from the front view ($X$-axis right, $Z$-axix up and $Y$-axis into the screen), and dragging perfectly horizontal applies a rotation around $Z$. Dragging perfectly vertically applies a rotation around $X$. Dragging diagonally seems to combine these two, so when dragging diagonally ain't I effectively setting two of the rotation parameters?

Comment: NOTE: I don't believe I'm able to set all three rotation parameters, unless I'm doing it from the 'axonometric view', i.e. where all three axises are visible at once.